# connect to ftp and download file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download specific file from ftp but I get error while trying to connect

```
import ftplib
url = 'ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/release-41/bacteria//fasta/bacteria_176_collection/_bacillus_aminovorans/cdna/'
ftp = ftplib.FTP(url)
```

error that I get: `UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)`

Comment: My guess is that this is caused by the specific url you use but don't show.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/release-41/bacteria//fasta/bacteria_176_collection/_bacillus_aminovorans/cdna/'
ftp = ftplib.FTP(url)
```

From [the documentation of ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP):

> class ftplib.FTP(host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', timeout=None, source_address=None)
>       Return a new instance of the FTP class. When host is given, the method call connect(host) is made.

In other words: the first argument is expected to be a hostname only, not a URL with `protocol://host/path`. If you want to connect to the server and make the server change to a specific path you need to do this in steps instead:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.ensemblgenomes.org','ftp','user@example.com')
ftp.cwd('/pub/release-41/bacteria//fasta/bacteria_176_collection/_bacillus_aminovorans/cdna/')
```